# Python Pandas datetime64 column filter by last business day in month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like to filter the df below by last business day in a month;

so the result should show only 2022-08-31 and 2022-07-29 as those were the last business days in the months.

Please keep in mind the original df has thousands of rows when writing the solution. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.to_datetime(['2022-08-01','2022-08-02','2022-08-03','2022-08-04','2022-08-31',
                   '2022-07-01','2022-07-02','2022-07-03','2022-07-04','2022-07-29'])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = d
print(df)

        date
0 2022-08-01
1 2022-08-02
2 2022-08-03
3 2022-08-04
4 2022-08-31
5 2022-07-01
6 2022-07-02
7 2022-07-03
8 2022-07-04
9 2022-07-29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.date_range`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with a `BM` frequency then [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter.

```
list_bm = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='BM').tolist()

out = df.loc[df['date'].isin(list_bm)]
```

**Note** : `'BM'` stands for *Business Month end frequency*.

```
print(out)

        date
4 2022-08-31
9 2022-07-29
```